# For Each... Next iterating one more times than it should?

Tags: excel, vb.net

If I copy from excel a single row comprised of three cells, where the value in cell 1, 2 and 3 is A, B and C respectively, I expect a single row of results in the loadsDG datagrid. However, what I get is a second row of results from a second iteration of the For Each... Next loop, even though only one row of values was copied from Excel, as demonstrated by the lack of a value in Col 2.

Please can someone explain what's going on? Here's the (edited, following comments below) code:

```
Public Class Form1

'Initialise the Datagrid
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    InitialiseLoadsDG()
End Sub

'Initialise Datagrid
Public Sub InitialiseLoadsDG()
    LoadsDG.Rows.Clear()
    LoadsDG.RowTemplate.Height = 20

    For i As Integer = 1 To 50
        LoadsDG.Rows.Add(i, "", "", "")
    Next

    LoadsDG.ClearSelection()
End Sub

'Paste copied values
Private Sub LoadsDG_KeyDown(sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles LoadsDG.PreviewKeyDown

    If e.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.V Then
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        For Each copiedLine As String In Clipboard.GetText.Split(vbNewLine)
            LoadsDG.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = copiedLine
            LoadsDG.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value = i
            i = i + 1
        Next
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

Here is what I expect:

```
        Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
   Row1           ABC      0
   Row2
```

Here is what I get:

```
        Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4
   Row1           ABC      0
   Row2                    1
```

UPDATE: Following Jimi's comment my Sub for pasting clipboard content works as expected. The code removes from copied excel content Carriage returns (vbCr), Line feeds (vbLf) and combined Carriage returns and Line feeds (vbCrLf), leaving only tab-delineated values. Note that each row of copied excel content occupies a *single element* (tab-delineated) in the copiedCells array. The rest of the code simply splits each tab-delineated (vbTab) row into individual excel cell values and pastes them into the appropriate loadsDG datagrid cell. Many thanks to all who responded. Here's the completed code:

```
'Paste copied values
Private Sub LoadsDG_KeyDown(sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventArgs) Handles LoadsDG.PreviewKeyDown

    If e.Control And e.KeyCode = Keys.V Then

        Dim copiedCells() As String = Clipboard.GetText.Split(New String() {vbCr, vbLf, vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim ii As Integer = 1

        For Each rowOfCells As String In copiedCells

            For Each cellValue As String In rowOfCells.Split(vbTab)
                LoadsDG.Rows(i).Cells(ii).Value = cellValue
                ii = ii + 1
            Next

            i = i + 1
            ii = 1
        Next

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: The question title is misleading, because there is no indication that VB.Net's foreach is doing anything wrong. You may want to add an Excel tag. And you may want to clarify how you are selecting the data that is being copied.

Comment: The code you've posted or the output you get don't match. You should post a [mcve]. Can you please edit your question to make sure it is correct?

Comment: @Richardissimo: Given the "1" in Row 2 of the "Here is what I get" results, this indicates that the loop has iterated not once, but twice, no? Also, I copy the three cells from excel by selection via mouse, then CTRL+C. Likewise, I paste the clipboard content to the datagrid by CTRL+V.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Sorry. I've edited my OP to provide you with the complete code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your `Split()` method generates empty *rows*. Use the overload that accepts `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`. You'll also get all the cells values separated by a Tab (`\t`) in a single string.

Comment: Note that you can also get a `CSV` format (as a MemoryStream, local encoding) and `XML Spreadsheet` format (as a MemoryStream, UTF8 encoding), `"System.String"` as a UTF16-LE string. Plus RTF, HTML and others.

Comment: @Jimi: As you can read above, my issue has now been resolved. Many thanks.